# Padding not coming as expected

Tags: html, size, padding

I have a doubt why div size increase unexpectedly when padding is given. I am developing an HTML keeping aspect ratio.

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="containerOuter">
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="top">
      <div class="top_inside"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="bottom_inside"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.containerOuter {
    background-color:silver;
}
.main_container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.top{
    width:96%;
    height:76%;
    padding:2%;
    background:#F00;
}
.bottom{
    width:96%;
    height:16%;
    padding:2%;
    background:#0F0;    
}
.top_inside{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
    background:#60C;
}
.bottom_inside{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#C0C;
}
```

JS:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.keepRatio = function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var ratio = 1.333333333;
        function ReSize() {
            var nw = $(window).height() * ratio;
            $this.css('width', nw + 'px');
            $this.css('height', $(window).height() + 'px');
        }
        $(window).resize(ReSize);
        ReSize();
    }
})( jQuery );
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#container').keepRatio();
});
```

when border-box is used the size is reduced

```
div {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing:border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
```

Can somebody explain this unexpected behavior ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is it doing, and what are you expecting? Do you have a fiddle or screenshots to help your explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how the browser interprets blocks by default, it adds padding to the width of the block. You should use CSS `box-sizing`.

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

More info about `box-sizing` you can find on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

First image has `box-sizing` set to `content-box`, second one to `border-box`

[image: Content box] [image: Border-box]

CSS used:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 200px;
}
.border-box {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: when border-box is used the size is reduced

Comment: `box-sizing` specifies that the size of a box should be measured according to either its content (default) or its total size including borders. If you use `box-sizing: border-box` then your div will have a set width, it will take padding and border inside, andthe content will have a reduced width.